# My CSS fails my javascript dropdown-menu slide effect

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

So if you want to see my menu go [here](http://www.gameplay-universe.uphero.com/).

Since I know you'll want my source, here's the CSS:

```
* {
margin: 0px;
}
#menu-container ul,
#menu-container li,
#menu-container span,
#menu-container a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}
#menu-container {
  text-align:center;  
  height: 49px;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 0 0;
  background: #141414;

  background:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAAxCAIAAACUDVRzAAAAA3NCSVQICAjb4U/gAAAALElEQVQImWMwMrJi+v//PxMDw3+m//8ZoPR/qBgDEhuXGLoeYswhXg8R5gAAdVpfoJ3dB5oAAAAASUVORK5CYII=) 100% 100%; 
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #32323a 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #32323a), color-stop(100%, #141414));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #32323a 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #32323a 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #32323a 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #32323a 0%, #141414 100%);
  border-bottom: 2px solid #0fa1e0;
}
#menu-container:after,
#menu-container ul:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
#menu-container a {
  background: #141414;
  background:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAAxCAIAAACUDVRzAAAAA3NCSVQICAjb4U/gAAAALElEQVQImWMwMrJi+v//PxMDw3+m//8ZoPR/qBgDEhuXGLoeYswhXg8R5gAAdVpfoJ3dB5oAAAAASUVORK5CYII=) 100% 100%; 
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #32323a 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #32323a), color-stop(100%, #141414));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #32323a 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #32323a 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #32323a 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #32323a 0%, #141414 100%);
  color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -4px;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 49px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#menu-container ul {
  list-style: none;
}
#menu-container > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -4px;
}
#menu-container > ul > li:hover:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #0fa1e0;
  margin-left: -10px;
}
#menu-container > ul > li:first-child > a {
  border-radius: 0px 0 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0 0 0;
}
#menu-container > ul > li:last-child > a {
  border-radius: 0 0px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0px 0 0;
}
#menu-container > ul > li.active > a {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #000000;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #000000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #000000;
  background: #070707;
  background:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAAxCAIAAACUDVRzAAAAA3NCSVQICAjb4U/gAAAALklEQVQImWNQU9Nh+v//PxMDw3+m//8ZkNj/mRgYIHxy5f//Z0BSi18e2TwS5QG4MGB54HL+mAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==) 100% 100%; 
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #26262c 0%, #070707 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #26262c), color-stop(100%, #070707));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #26262c 0%, #070707 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #26262c 0%, #070707 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #26262c 0%, #070707 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #26262c 0%, #070707 100%);
}
#menu-container > ul > li:hover > a {
  background: #070707;
  background:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAAxCAIAAACUDVRzAAAAA3NCSVQICAjb4U/gAAAALklEQVQImWNQU9Nh+v//PxMDw3+m//8ZkNj/mRgYIHxy5f//Z0BSi18e2TwS5QG4MGB54HL+mAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==) 100% 100%; 
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #26262c 0%, #070707 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #26262c), color-stop(100%, #070707));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #26262c 0%, #070707 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #26262c 0%, #070707 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #26262c 0%, #070707 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #26262c 0%, #070707 100%);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #000000;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #000000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #000000;
}
#menu-container .has-sub {
  z-index: 1;
}
#menu-container .has-sub:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
#menu-container .has-sub ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
#menu-container .has-sub ul li {
  *margin-bottom: -1px;
}
#menu-container .has-sub ul li a {
  background: #0fa1e0;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #6fc7ec;
  filter: none;
  font-size: 11px;
  display: block;
  line-height: 120%;
  padding: 10px;
}
#menu-container .has-sub ul li:hover a {
  background: #0c7fb0;
}
#menu-container .has-sub .has-sub:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
#menu-container .has-sub .has-sub ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
#menu-container .has-sub .has-sub ul li a {
  background: #0c7fb0;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #6db2d0;
}
#menu-container .has-sub .has-sub ul li a:hover {
  background: #095c80;
}
#menu-container {
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #888;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #888;
box-shadow: 0 0 10px #888;
}
li {
    font-size: 0
}
```

And JavaScript:

```
    var menu=function(){
    var t=15,z=50,s=6,a;
    function dd(n){this.n=n; this.h=[]; this.c=[]}
    dd.prototype.init=function(p,c){
        a=c; var w=document.getElementById(p), s=w.getElementsByTagName('ul'), l=s.length, i=0;
        for(i;i<l;i++){
            var h=s[i].parentNode; this.h[i]=h; this.c[i]=s[i];
            h.onmouseover=new Function(this.n+'.st('+i+',true)');
            h.onmouseout=new Function(this.n+'.st('+i+')');
        }
    }
    dd.prototype.st=function(x,f){
        var c=this.c[x], h=this.h[x], p=h.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
        clearInterval(c.t); c.style.overflow='hidden';
        if(f){
            p.className+=' '+a;
            if(!c.mh){c.style.display='block'; c.style.height=''; c.mh=c.offsetHeight; c.style.height=0}
            if(c.mh==c.offsetHeight){c.style.overflow='visible'}
            else{c.style.zIndex=z; z++; c.t=setInterval(function(){sl(c,1)},t)}
        }else{p.className=p.className.replace(a,''); c.t=setInterval(function(){sl(c,-1)},t)}
    }
    function sl(c,f){
        var h=c.offsetHeight;
        if((h<=0&&f!=1)||(h>=c.mh&&f==1)){
            if(f==1){c.style.filter=''; c.style.opacity=1; c.style.overflow='visible'}
            clearInterval(c.t); return
        }
        var d=(f==1)?Math.ceil((c.mh-h)/s):Math.ceil(h/s), o=h/c.mh;
        c.style.opacity=o; c.style.filter='alpha(opacity='+(o*100)+')';
        c.style.height=h+(d*f)+'px'
    }
    return{dd:dd}
}();
```

And the HTML:

```
<div id='menu-container'>
<ul id='menu' class="menu">
<li class='active'><a href='/'><span>Home</span></a></li>
<li class='has-sub'><a href='/games/'><span>Games</span></a>
<ul>
<li><a href='/games/dota-2/'><span>Dota 2</span></a></li>
<li><a href='/games/cs-go/'><span>CS: GO</span></a></li>
<li><a href='/games/css/'><span>CS: Source</span></a></li>
<li><a href='/games/terraria/'><span>Terraria</span></a></li>
<li class='last'><a href='/games/minecraft/'><span>Minecraft</span></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class='has-sub'><a href='/about.html'><span>About Us</span></a>
<ul>
<li><a href='http://www.youtube.com/user/'><span>Our YouTube Channel</span></a></li>
<li><a href='/faq-list.html'><span>Our FAQs/Q&amp;A List</span></a></li>
<li><a href='/feed-news.rss'><span>Our RSS Feed</span></a></li>
<li><a href='/wiki/'><span>Our Wiki</span></a></li>
<li><a href='#'><span>Our Blog</span></a></li>
<li class='last'><a href='/privacy.html'><span>Privacy Policy</span></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class='has-sub last'><a href='/contact.html'><span>Contact Us</span></a>
<ul>
<li class='last'><a href='/forums/'><span>Forums</span></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var menu=new menu.dd("menu");
menu.init("menu","menuhover");
</script>
```

After I added "text-align:center;" to my CSS, when I hover to the menu the slide animation goes in the down direction, but it goes to right too. How to make it go down  only?
So I want when you hover on a menu the slide to be only to the bottom NOT to the right.

Comment: When we say that we want code in questions, we dont want ALL of your code.  We want the parts that are related to the problem (which you should be able to figure out without help)

Comment: Do you mean [like this](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/centered-dropdown-menus) (demo page [here](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/centered-dropdown-menus.html)) or [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/gNanu/)? It's a matter of centering the children elements, not an issue with the `text-align:center`. Changing `text-align` centers it in reference to the page and doesn't change the positioning of the children at all

Comment: Well I actually mean that when you hover on one of the parent elements the child elements go down (slide down) and when they stop they go right. I don't want them going to the right - just slide down.

Comment: @PowerUser Can you be more clear? Do you mean you want it to [look like the right version?](http://imgur.com/dDQOnNW)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a negative margin being inherited by links in the menu [#menu-container a]. So your menu items end up 4 pixels wider than the menu. You can reset the margin to 0 by adding to the more specific selector like this:

```
#menu-container .has-sub ul li a { margin-right: 0 }
```